# Oracle select index columns along with data type?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, types

I am using the following SQL to grab index columns for a table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM DBA_IND_COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE' AND TABLE_OWNER = 'SCHEMA'";
```

I want to adjust this SQL such that I grab the index columns and their data type:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE 
FROM DBA_IND_COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE' AND TABLE_OWNER = 'SCHEMA'";
```

But this gives an invalid identifier error for "DATA_TYPE". Is there a way to do this without creating another query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `DBA_TAB_COLUMNS` to your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COL.COLUMN_NAME, COL.DATA_TYPE 
FROM DBA_IND_COLUMNS IND
  INNER JOIN DBA_TAB_COLUMNS COL
    ON ( IND.TABLE_OWNER = COL.OWNER AND IND.TABLE_NAME = COL.TABLE_NAME AND IND.COLUMN_NAME = COL.COLUMN_NAME)
WHERE IND.TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE' AND TABLE_OWNER = 'SCHEMA'
```